# Django, Can't get delete button to work

Tags: python, django

I have a section of my site where an admin can add a widget. However the delete button to delete any current widgets is not working. I have this code implemented else where on my site and it is working.

I copied the same code from the other section of my site where this is being used. The other section of my site which uses this code is a little different in that a post can only be deleted be the user who created it, and the widgets can be delete by any user with the "access_level" field is equal to "admin". However, I am the only admin so it should still work. The page that the widget stuff is displayed on is only accessible if your "access_level" is equal to admin so I don't need to validate whether or not they have the permission before deleting. Please help.

widget_list.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="widgets-list">
        {% for widget in widget_list %}
            <h3>{{ widget.name }}</h3>
            <h3>{{ widget.widget_order }}</h3>
            <div>
                <p>{{ widget.body }}</p>
            </div>
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <a class="auth-user-options" href="{% url 'adminpanel:delete-widget' pk=widget.pk %}">Delete</a>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Adminpanel app views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from adminpanel.forms import WidgetForm
from adminpanel.models import Widget
from django.utils import timezone

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse,reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from braces.views import SelectRelatedMixin
from django.views.generic import (TemplateView,ListView,
                                    DetailView,CreateView,
                                    UpdateView,DeleteView)

# Create your views here.
class CreateWidgetView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'index.html'
    form_class = WidgetForm
    model = Widget

    def form_valid(self,form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('adminpanel:widgets')

class SettingsListView(ListView):
    model = Widget
    ordering = ['widget_order']

class DeleteWidget(LoginRequiredMixin,SelectRelatedMixin,DeleteView):
    model = Widget
    select_related = ('Widget',)
    success_url = reverse_lazy('adminpanel:widget')

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(user_id=self.request.user.id)

    def delete(self,*args,**kwargs):
        return super().delete(*args,**kwargs)
```

Project url spy:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include
from accounts import views
from colorsets import views
from colors import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$',views.home,name='index'),
    url(r'^accounts/',include('accounts.urls',namespace='accounts')),
    url(r'^colorsets/',include('colorsets.urls',namespace='colorsets')),
    url(r'^adminpanel/',include('adminpanel.urls',namespace='adminpanel')),
]
```

Adminpanel app urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from adminpanel import views

app_name = 'adminpanel'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^widgets/',views.SettingsListView.as_view(),name='widgets'),
    url(r'^new/$',views.CreateWidgetView.as_view(),name='create-widget'),
    url(r'^delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.DeleteWidget.as_view(),name='delete-widget'),
]
```

**EDIT:** Here is the error I'm getting I forgot to add it.

```
FieldError at /adminpanel/delete/10/
Cannot resolve keyword 'user_id' into field. Choices are: body, id, name, widget_order
```

and the traceback points to this:

```
/Users/garrettlove/Desktop/colors/adminpanel/views.py in get_queryset
        return queryset.filter(user_id=self.request.user.id) ...
▶ Local vars
```

Adminpanel app models.py (widget model):

```
from django.db import models
from adminpanel.choices import *

# Create your models here.
class Widget(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    widget_order = models.IntegerField(blank=False,unique=True)
    display_name = models.IntegerField(choices=WIDGET_NAME_CHOICES,default=1)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Can you add a full stacktrace of the error?

Comment: @wencakisa Sorry I forgot that, just added it.

Comment: Can you please add your `models.py` too? (Especially your `Widget` model)

Comment: @wencakisa Just added the widget model, do you want to see my posts (ColorSets) model too?

Comment: @Garrett Shouldn't you have a foreignkey between widgets and users?

Comment: That's if you're trying to remove widgets by a user (I'm guessing that by your attempt at `user_id=`)... if you're trying to remove individual widgets, then surely you just want it based on it's id only.

Comment: @JonClements No, not by user, just any user with `access_level` field equal to "admin". I tried removing the `user` part so now it's just `return queryset.filter(user_id=self.request.id)` but it still gives me that error.

Answer (score 0):

As your error is saying:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'user_id' into field.
```

And it points to this line:

```
return queryset.filter(user_id=self.request.user.id)
```

It's that your `queryset` model does not have a `user_id` field. In your `DeleteWidget` view you have specified `model = Widget`
and as you see in your `Widget` model, you have the following fields: `body, id, name, widget_order`. There is no `user_id` field.

---

You need to change your filtering logic. If you want to have a related [`User`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) model, you should use [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) relation and then you can filter by the `User`'s `id`.

In your `models.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Widget(models.Model):
    # ...
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And then in your `DeleteWidget`'s `get_queryset`, you can do the following:

```
return queryset.filter(user__id=self.request.user.id)
# __________________________^
# Note that there is a double underscore here!
# This is because Django uses double underscore for accessing related models in queries.
```

Comment: What if I don't want it to be attached to a specific user but rather any user that has `access_level` equal to "admin" in the `UserLevels` model?

Comment: It's now giving me a `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'garrett'` when I try to migrate it and even when I delete that and go back to what I had I can't migrate it at all without getting that same error.